# WP Custom Tag Search using a custom form?

Tags: wordpress

## UPDATE #1

[I found this link here, which looks like a cleaner way of handling this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/199240/allow-visitors-to-search-by-multiple-tags-specific-ids)

Replicating his example, it seems like it won't work until WP 4.4, as I suffered the same issue as the poster on that link had:

> The URL would show http://example.com/?s=searchterm&tag[]=key-word1&tag[]=key-word2

This would break the tag search. Removing the [] would then only search the last tag on the URL, which defeats the purpose.

*Anyone know a way around this?*

### Original Question

So I have a WP page that I am using a video library. *All the videos are labeled with different WP tags and categories.* For example, a video may contain the tags:

> new movies, cool, trending, action, thriller

**So I would want to do a search for multiple tags simultaneously.**

I know that I can query multiple tags just by using this notation:

> https://example.com/tag/key-word1+key-word2+key-word3/

So my idea was to create a form that user would submit, which would go to a custom php page that would parse the inputs and redirect to the correct page.

For example, suppose I have this form:

```
<form method="post" action="parse.php">
  <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="Action" value="Action" />Action</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="Comedy" value="Comedy" />Comedy</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="Drama" value="Drama" />Drama</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="Old-Movies" value="Old-Movies" />Old Movies</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="New-Movies" value="New-Movies" />New Movies</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="Lame" value="Lame" />Lame</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="Cool" value="Cool" />Cool</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="Thriller" value="Thriller" />Thriller</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="Boring" value="Boring" />Boring</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="Trending" value="Trending" />Trending</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="Unpopular" value="Unpopular" />Unpopular</li>
  </ul>
  <input type="submit" value="Search Now!" />
</form>
```

### parse.php

```
<?php
$input_vars = $_POST;
$count = count($input_vars);
$i = 0;
$uri = "http://example.com/tag/";

foreach($_POST as $name=>$value) {
    ++$i;
    if($i !== $count)
        $uri .= $value."+";
    else
        $uri .= $value;
}
$uri .= "/";

header("Location: $uri");
exit;
?>
```

While this seems to work, I'm not sure if this would be considered a "best practices" method of solving this problem.

What would be the best way to handle such a search that is looking for multiple tags in a WP site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how this does work as your `input` tags need `name` attributes. Might have been an omission.

```
 <li><input name="type[]" type="checkbox" value="Action" />Action</li>
 <li><input name="type[]" type="checkbox" value="Comedy" />Comedy</li>
 ...
```

Also, by using `type[]` you ensure that these are grouped in array in `$_POST`

```
 $input_vars = $_POST['type'];
 $count = count($input_vars);
 $i = 0;
 $uri = "http://example.com/tag/";

 foreach($input_vars as $name=>$value) {
 ++$i;
 if($i !== $count)
    $uri .= $value."+";
 else
    $uri .= $value;
 }
 $uri .= "/";

 header("Location: $uri");
 exit;
```

Also, you may want to reconsider creating a new page to check these values and hook into "template_redirect" to perform the redirect.

```
add_action("wp_redirect", function()
{
     $input_vars = $_POST['type'];
     $count = count($input_vars);
     $i = 0;
     $uri = "http://example.com/tag/";

     foreach($input_vars as $name=>$value) {
         ++$i;
         if($i !== $count)
             $uri .= $value."+";
         else
             $uri .= $value;
     }
     $uri .= "/";

     wp_redirect($uri);
    exit;   
});`
```

Comment: it was an omission on my part, but using the array would save a line of code. I am not too familiar with working with WP php. What would doing the template_redirect entail?

Comment: [link]https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect.

Have also amended answer.

Comment: Zakalwe - I updated the question with a link to another similar question on the stack network that appears to be a cleaner solution. However, it does have issues I don't know how to get around.